# How to remove title bar from terminal in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: gnome-terminal

[image]

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5dTo.png)
I want to remove title bar from gnome-terminal as it takes to much space on my 13 inch laptop. I have tried this command:

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings headerbar "@mb false"
```

but it doesn't work. Anyone knows the working solution?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to remove it too, but couldn't find anything about it that would work so I write some css to remove it myself.
Here's the [repo](https://github.com/safesintesi/terminal-guillotine).

I found the correct selectors reading several themes for gtk like [catppuccin](https://github.com/catppuccin/gtk).